# NodeJS Sessions (Or dont share values between users)

Tags: node.js, express

I have this simples nodejs app.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var cont = 0
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    cont ++;
    response.send('Cont ' + cont)
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

I would like cont value start in 0 for each session (or user). This snippset share cont value between sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `express-session` module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Answer (score 0):

I follow ponury-kostek's sugestion and install 'express-session', this is my code now.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere'}));
app.use(bodyParser());
var cont = 0;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '';
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.cont++
    html += 'cont session is: ' + req.session.cont;
  }
  res.send(html);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

But how set initial value for cont and iterated it?

Comment: Just add 'if(req.session.cont === undefined) req.session.cont = 0;' before 'req.session.cont++'